# React Native - How to call a function from a child component?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to make a Timer component which should start when its start function is called from a parent component:

Timer:

```
class Timer extends Component {
   start = () => {
      //starts the timer here
   }
}
```

Parent:

```
class Parent extends Component {
   render () {
      <Timer /> // how do I call the start function from this parent component?
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the use case for this situation? Could you not just call the `start` from the Timer component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may call the child function from the parent by setting reference to the child.

```
//Child
class Timer extends Component {
    start = () => {
        //starts the timer here
    }
}

//Parent
class Parent extends Component {

    rende() {
        <Timer ref={ ( component ) => this.Timer = component }/>
    }

   someParentFunction() {
       this.Timer.start();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should trigger change a prop from `<Timer>` and then start the timer in the `componentWillReceiveProps`. Small example

```
class Parent extends Component {
    //set the state to this.state={runTimerStart: false}
    onParentAction = () => {   //call this onParentAction function when you want to start the timer
        this.setState({runTimerStart: true})
    }
    render () {
        <Timer runStart={this.state.runTimerStart}/> 
    }
}
```

And in `<Timer>`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if(nextProps.runTimerStart === true){
    //Perform some operation, call your start function
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the following is really bad practice, typically if you found yourself in a situation where you need to pass from child to parent there's a larger issue.

Also this solution should not be used verbatim but rather give you a really good idea of how to pass a function back to the parent from the child

```
class Timer extends Component {
   componentDidMount() {
      this.props.setIt(this.start)
   }

   start = () => {
      //starts the timer here
   }
}

class Parent extends Component {

   setIt = (startTrigger) => {
     startTrigger() // You now have access to this function to do what you wish
   }

   render () {
      <Timer setStartTrigger={this.setIt} />
   }
}
```